# Shall strings pointed by paramaters to PySys_SetArgvEx() be kept in memory until Py_Finalize()?

Tags: python, c, python-c-api, cpython, python-embedding

i have the following piece of code

```
int nArgs;
if (LPWSTR * const szArglist = CommandLineToArgvW(GetCommandLineW(), &nArgs))
{
  PySys_SetArgvEx(nArgs, szArglist, false);
  LocalFree(szArglist);
}
```

I cannot find in Python [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.4/c-api/init.html#c.PySys_SetArgv) if memory pointed by szArglist shall be preserved until Python is shutdown or i can free it immediately.

Can anybody put some light on this, please?

Thank you!
Vladimir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Python C API looks like it is using a new PyList object to fill out the args, and is allocating its own memory for the char* arguments.

On strings longer than 1 characters, PySys_SetArgvEx will malloc its own memory for the string.

So it's safe to delete any memory allocated that you passed to PySys_SetArgvEx.